# Check if keys exists in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a legacy code which converts lists to dictionary by doing some manipulation as shown below

```
var items = await processTask;
var itemDict = items.ToDictionary(dto => dto.ClientId, dto => mapper.ConvertTo(dto, hj));
```

But recently we started to see this issue which looks like we are getting duplicate keys

```
An item with the same key has already been added
```

What's the best way to fix this so that if duplicate keys comes it should not throw exception but we can log it. Can we do this in linq or it has to be done in for loop?

Comment: `var items = await processTask;` has a duplicate so fix this.

Comment: yeah I know there is some data issue but I want to see if data gets messed up, it should not throw exception

Comment: What I'm suggesting that if you show the code which results in items.. aka what is queried and why, seeing as it contains duplicates... if the  records are coming from a db for example.. then you could simply remove the duplicate from the db... but as you don't show the code its hard to say. The code is telling what the problem is, what the "best" way to fix this is to not allow the code to have a duplicate, where there should not be. Depending on how the data is obtained the "best" solution may vary.

Comment: the way you worded it, i understood it as that processTask shouldn't of had duplicates.. not that you want to do some post processing. if post processing is needed then @T.S. answer looks good, otherwise fix the source rather than handling things which should be exceptions, hard to know when you cant see the code or intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't eliminate dups while in `ToDictionary`. You have to do something before `ToDictionary` to eliminate it, like call `Distinct` or similar. But may be better to have an explicit loop, where you get opportunity to do something with a dupe

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(); // whatever mapper converts to
foreach(var dto in items)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(dto.ClientId))
    {
        // log duplicate here or do something
        continue;
    }

    dict.Add(dto.ClientId, mapper.ConvertTo(dto, hj));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with LINQ using [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var itemDict = items
    .GroupBy(dto => dto.ClientId)
    .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => mapper.ConvertTo(gr.First(), hj))
```

Also logging duplicates will make this code less elegant.

Comment: Is this better in terms of performance? Or a simple for loop will be better here? Just want to make sure since this code will be called under heavy load.

Comment: LINQ is not a cost-free abstraction in general and in this particular case also.

Comment: @dragons single loop always better than multiple manipulations